# Error Visual Studio 17 - Cannot open the workbook in the designer

Tags: excel, visual-studio, ms-office, vsto, office-interop

When I try to create a new project for "Excel 2013 and 2016 VSTO Workbook" using Visual Studio 2017, I get the error "The project cannot be created..". The help is not helpful as it suggest repairing Visual Studio which I have done and I get the same error. No Excel workbooks are open.

[Issue screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzsO0.png)

I am running:

1. Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise
2. Microsoft Office 2016 (16.0.7301.1021   x64)
3. Windows 10 Enterprise

The problem disappear in an other computer with same configuration except a different Office version (16.04.4417.1000   x64). It could be an Office 2016 version problem?

I already tried to rollback my Office 2016 through Click-to-Run method (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2770432/how-to-revert-to-an-earlier-version-of-office-2013-or-office-2016-clic) but it doesn't work. I also tried to uninstall and reinstall Office 2016 without results.

Can you help me to resolve this issue?

Thank you for the support

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved the problem. I uninstalled my Office version and I installed a new one downloaded directly from Microsoft site(trial version).